# How do I display the output from for loop as a table in PHP

Tags: php, html

My output is in the form of a 2d array. I have uploaded a sample file and the output is displayed like a paragraph. I want it to be displayed as a table.

Code:

```
<?php
require("reader.php"); // php excel reader
$file="sample.xls";
$connection=new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(); // our main object
$connection->read($file);
$startrow=1;
$endrow=1000;

for($i=$startrow;$i<$endrow;$i++){ // we read row to row

    for($j=1;$j<=30;$j++) {
        // so we get [2][3] and [3][3]
        echo $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$j]; 
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to _not_ `echo "\n";` in the inner for loop. Or are you asking how to output it as an HTML table? Because if you're viewing the output in a browser, these `"\n"`s aren't going to show up anyway.

Comment: Just output HTML table markup. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: 1. Do you mean an HTML Table? 2. Do you know any HTML?

Comment: Sounds kinda loop sql-php table

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
echo "<table>";

for($i=$startrow;$i<$endrow;$i++){ // we read row to row
   echo "<tr>";
    for($j=1;$j<=30;$j++) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$j]; 
        echo "</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```